# Why does empty() "not" exist?

Tags: php, php-7

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
var_dump([
    defined('empty'),
    function_exists('empty'),
    is_callable('empty'),
    empty(0),
    empty(1),
    ]);

array (size=5)
  0 => boolean false
  1 => boolean false
  2 => boolean false
  3 => boolean true
  4 => boolean false
```

I can clearly use `empty`, so why does PHP report it to not be defined, not exist, and not be callable?

Comment: Because it's a language construct :P

Comment: @Darren Yeah, just stumbled upon it in the Callbacks manual page 

Comment: Just noticed your answer haha!

Answer (score 3):

And then I found it of course...

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo, empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print or unset().
>
> -- [Callbacks / Callables: Passing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php#language.types.callable.passing)